# Issue with computed property when trying to sort array in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    // sort: item,
    sortKey: 'name',
    checked: false,
    searchString: "",
    items: [{
        price: '1',
        name: 'mm'
      },
      {
        price: '22',
        name: 'aa'
      },
      {
        price: '55',
        name: 'dd'
      },
      {
        price: '77',
        name: 'gg'
      },
      {
        price: '123',
        name: 'kk'
      },
      {
        price: '53',
        name: 'mn'
      },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    sortedItems: function() {
      let searchString = this.searchString;
      const sortedArray = this.items.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[this.sortKey] < b[this.sortKey]) return -1
        if (a[this.sortKey] > b[this.sortKey]) return 1
        return 0
      });
      if (!searchString) {
        return sortedArray;
      } else {
        searchString = searchString.trim().toLowerCase();
        const search_array = sortedArray.filter((item) => {
          if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
            return item;
          }
        });
        return search_array;
      }
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<p>sortKey = {{sortKey}}</p>
<li v-for="item in sortedItems">
  <input class="checkbox-align" type="checkbox" :value="item.name" id="productname" v-model="item.checked" /> {{ item.price }} - {{ item.name }}
</li>

<div class="bbb">
  <button @click="sortKey = 'name'">name</buttton><br />
      <button @click="sortKey = 'price'">price</buttton>
  </div>
```

Issue with computed property when trying to sort array in Vuejs? I am getting error as ---vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties(sortedItem)

My code is working fine in Codepen, But i am not sure why it is not working in the vscode,  when executing locally. What does it mean exactly like  ---vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties

Comment: [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) will modify the array it is sorting. I suspect you need to clone the array first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to modify the data variables inside the computed property. Thats the reason its throwing that error.

Pls see the modified code below

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    // sort: item,
    sortKey: 'name',
    checked: false,
    searchString: "",
    items: [{
        price: '1',
        name: 'mm'
      },
      {
        price: '22',
        name: 'aa'
      },
      {
        price: '55',
        name: 'dd'
      },
      {
        price: '77',
        name: 'gg'
      },
      {
        price: '123',
        name: 'kk'
      },
      {
        price: '53',
        name: 'mn'
      },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    sortedItems: function() {
      let searchString = this.searchString;
      let itemsClone = [...this.items]; // Change added
      const sortedArray = itemsClone.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[this.sortKey] < b[this.sortKey]) return -1
        if (a[this.sortKey] > b[this.sortKey]) return 1
        return 0
      });
      if (!searchString) {
        return sortedArray;
      } else {
        searchString = searchString.trim().toLowerCase();
        const search_array = sortedArray.filter((item) => {
          if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
            return item;
          }
        });
        return search_array;
      }
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example-1">
<p>sortKey = {{sortKey}}</p>
<li v-for="item in sortedItems">
  <input class="checkbox-align" type="checkbox" :value="item.name" id="productname" v-model="item.checked" /> {{ item.price }} - {{ item.name }}
</li>

<div class="bbb">
  <button @click="sortKey = 'name'">name</buttton><br />
      <button @click="sortKey = 'price'">price</buttton>
  </div>
</div>
```